# Computing Separatrix of Second-Order Nonlinear Autonomous ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

Numerically solving differential equations of the form

```
{x''[t] == f[x[t], x'[t]], x[0] == x0, x'[tm] == 0}
```

where `tm` is large, typically is quite difficult, if the linearization of f[x[tm], 0] about the solution of `f[x[tm], 0] == 0` is `a x[tm]` with `a > 0`; *i. e.*, if the solution coincides with the separatrix of the ODE at large `tm`.  This is because even infinitesimal numerical errors grow exponentially there.

Section 2.2 of the [Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations](https://www.crcpress.com/Handbook-of-Exact-Solutions-for-Ordinary-Differential-Equations/Zaitsev-Polyanin/p/book/9781584882978) uses the transformation `x'[t] == w[x]` to reduce the order of the ODE by one,

```
w'[x] w[x] == f[x, w[x]]
```

Then, true to its name, the book solves several particular cases of `f` analytically.  I wish to know whether solving this equation numerically for autonomous second-order ODEs without analytical solutions and then inverting the transform would be easier than numerically solving the original ODE.

As a test case, consider the equation

```
eq = x''[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]^2) + x'[t] + x'[t]^2
```

which is compact but nonetheless nonlinear in both `x[t]` and `x'[t]`.  The separatrix lies at `x == 0`.  It can, in fact, be solved directly by

```
tm = 10; 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]);
NDSolve[{eq, x[0] == 1/2, x'[tm] == c x[tm]}, x, {t, 0, tm}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == 1/2, 
    x'[0] == -30724/100000}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
Plot[x[t] /. %, {t, 0, tm}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, w}]
```

[image]

but only with an excellent initial guess.  Even then, increasing `tm` much beyond ten causes `NDSolve` to fail.

My question, then, is, can this ODE be solved numerically by means of the transformation above with larger `tm` and without an excellent initial guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ODE in the question can be solved as follows.

```
eqw = eq /. {x''[t] -> w'[x] w[x], x'[t] -> w[x], x[t] -> x}
(* w[x] w'[x] == x (1 - x^2) + w[x] + w[x]^2 *)
```

The separatrix occurs at `x == 0`, and `w[0] == 0` as well.  To understand the behavior near `x == 0`, linearize the equation and assume that `w[x]` is approximately equal to `a x`, with `a` a constant.  The linearized equation then is `a^2 x == x + a x`, and `a` is determined by

```
a /. Solve[a^2 x == x + a x, a]
(* {1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])} *)
```

If `1 > x0 > 0`, the desired expression for `a` must be negative; conversely, it must be positive for `0 > x0 > -1`.  Let us choose `x0 == 1/2`, in which case set

```
c = First@%
(* 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]) *)
```

Then, the equation for `w` is solved in about a second by

```
offset = 10^-10;
sw = Flatten@NDSolve[{eqw, w[offset] == c offset}, w[x], {x, offset, 1/2}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30];
Plot[(w[x] /. sw), {x, offset, 1/2}, AxesLabel -> {x, w}]
```

[image]

Finally, the transformation is inverted in a few seconds by

```
xp = x'[t] == Piecewise[{{(w[x] /. sw /. x -> x[t]), x[t] > offset}, 
    {c, offset > x[t] > 0}}];
Flatten@Quiet@NDSolve[{xp, x[0] == 1/2}, x[t], {t, 0, 40}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
Plot[x[t] /. %, {t, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, x}]
```

[image]

In effect, the approach just described decomposes one second-order boundary-value problem into two first-order initial-value problems.  For completeness, note that `x[t] == offset` occurs at

```
t /. FindRoot[(x[t] /. %%) == offset, {t, 30}]
(* 36.0493 *)
```

The last `NDSolve` integration could have been stopped there, and an approximate analytical solution, `offset Exp[c (t - 36.0493)]` used for larger `t`.

Incidentally, although the approach described here could be applied when `f` depends on `x` only, the method of the [answer to 140328](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140414/1063) seems simpler.